# Feature importance difference in two similar machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, xgboost, features, stacking

**Situation 1:**

I have trained a text classification model (Model 1) which gives me a probability of true class as X. I have also trained a classification model (Model 2) using only the categorical and numeric data. Both the models are used to predict the same true class; just the features differ.
I  used a random forest classifier on the probabilities returned by Model 1 and Model 2(taking them as input features) and got similar performance metrics(Accuracy, Precision recall). **feature importance was 49% for model 1 and 51% for model 2.**

**Situation 2:**

I used the probability X of text classification model as an input feature to the Model 2(which contained categorical and numeric features). The performance was almost similar to Situation 1 but here the feature importance of the final model indicated that **text model probability had higher importance around 68% and rest of the features had lesser importance.**

I want to understand the difference in feature importance of both situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In 2nd case, you are not comparing apple to apple.*

Let's say we have 4 Features and all are equally good [*Also, No interaction]*.

**Case I -**

We created two Models using 2 Features each

*Model I - F1/F2

Model II- F3/F4*

Comparing these two Models as Features will give you an Idea about F1/F2-combined compared to F3/F4-combined. *This is your Case - I.*

**Case II -**

If you will compare *F1/F2-combined, F3(alone), and F4(alone)*, definitely F1/F2 combined will have high importance.

 The output probability of a Model using two Features is basically holding the information of both the Features together.

Comment: Which case should I then go ahead with? How can I decide on that?